# Add active connections to channel when it's created

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I am trying to prevent who can see events for a particular page, so I am determining and storing the ids of which users have access to a particular page. In channels.js, I can add users to the new page-level channel in app.on('connection') by iterating through the pages like this: app.channel('page-' + pageId).join(connection)

The problem is that a user doesn't start getting broadcasts from that page until after they refresh the browser and re-connect.

What I want to happen is have all connections for a an allowed user start getting broadcasts when the page is created. Is there a way to do that in channels.js, or can I tell it who to start broadcasting to in a hook for the page creation?

*Editing to add the last thing I tried. "Users-pages" is an associative entity that links Users and Pages.*

```
app.service('users-pages').on('created', userPage => {
    const { connections } = app.channel(app.channels).filter(connection =>
      connection.user.id === userPage.userId
    )
    app.channel('page-' + userPage.pageId).join(connections)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ***app.channel('page-' + pageId).join(connections)*** wasn't working for me. But looping through each connection works fine:

```
connections.forEach(connection => {
  app.channel('page-' + userPage.pageId).join(connection)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [keeping channels updated](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html#keeping-channels-updated) documentation should have the answer you are looking for. It uses the `users` service but can be updated for pages accordingly which could look like this:

```
app.service('pages').on('created', page => {
  // Assuming there is a reference of `users` on the page object
  page.users.forEach(user => {
    // Find all connections for this user
    const { connections } = app.channel(app.channels).filter(connection =>
      connection.user._id === user._id
    );

    app.channel('page-' + pageId).join(connections);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. "app.channel('page-' + pageId).join(connections)" didn't seem to work for me, but I was able to get my code to do what I wanted.